# How to separate UI language from node's language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a site that uses 3 languages, namely English, Polish and Russian. And we have content editors with 3 native languages. Now, most of the times Russian guy will want Russian UI and will be editing Russian nodes. But sometimes he will need to correct nodes written in Polish. He will not want his UI to turn to Polish when doing that, of course.

Is there a way to allow users to select their default admin language? Desired effect for nodes is:

- http://example.com/node/435 displayed in layout based on node's language (let's say, Polish)
- http://example.com/en/node/435 redirected to proper language (here http://example.com/pl/node/435) - that's pretty much easy and was answered in many places.
- http://example.com/node/435/edit should be opened in UI based on user's preference set in a profile field, for example, or redirected to proper language edit path like http://example.com/pl/node/435/edit
- http://example.com/en/node/435/edit should be redirected to http://example.com/node/435/edit or http://example.com/pl/node/435/edit (consistent with previous point).

If possible, I want this globally, for all admin pages, not only node edits, but of course node edits will be most common = most important to me.

Comment: Have you checked the Admin Language module ? It seems to answer part of your question and specs and does have a 7.X release... It doesn't, however, allow different admin languages per user.

Comment: @mariomc actually that answers the part that wasn't easy to find and made me ask this question. Post it as an answer please, so I can check it accepted. Now I wonder how did I fail to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot this in my initial comment but you can actually solve this by installing [Entity Translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation)!

It separates entity and interface translation. With both you can specify different language negotiation schemes. In *admin/config/regional/language/configure* simply set the user's language setting as the highest priority in the interface language negotiation queue.

By having URL as the first criteria and user preference in the content language negotiation queue you can attain this functionality you documented.